# Is PHP Azure going to get PHP 5.5 or 5.6?

Tags: php, azure, azure-cloud-services

I have been running a PHP web service on Azure VMs because of an older problem with the Azure PHP Powershell scripts, which has since been fixed. However, it seems that the PHP cloud services only support up to PHP 5.4 which is useless for loads of new features and specifically, in my case, the latest Amazon SDK. I want to change back because cloud services are much better supported by MS and are slightly cheaper than VMs.

I can't find where this PHP Azure project is actively maintained and whether there are any plans for 5.5 or 5.6 support or whether there is a way to get this to work on cloud services as opposed to VMs?

Comment: Scratch the second part of the question. I've found how to do it manually if I need to but it would be better if it can be done automatically.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question for Azure support, not relating to PHP code.

Comment: "I can't find where this PHP Azure project is actively maintained" - how about https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-availability-of-php-7-rc7-x86-on-azure-web-app/ ? Very first google search result ;-)

Comment: That link like most of the others is for Azure web sites, which is not the same as cloud services. Web sites are cheaper but over provisioned, so better for low volume stuff.

Comment: @devon, it might be a question to Azure support but it is also a programming question because someone might know how to get PHP 5.5 on cloud services either by hack or by some hidden knowledge.

Comment: As this thread is on-hold so that i just can leave a simple comment here. actually, we can configure custom PHP runtime in cloud service for worker role or web role. You can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-php-create-web-role/#customize-the-built-in-php-runtime

Answer (score 1):

The current Web App Application Settings let you choose the follow PHP Versions:

1. 5.4
2. 5.5
3. 5.6

Maybe you are using a old service. Try the new "Web App".

Comment: This is for web sites, not for cloud services

Comment: Webapp its the new cloudapp, some services changes on December 15, mobile services now is Mobile App, other new are Web App, API App, thats way you see in the portal Cloudservice (classic) at the bottom of the home dashboard and in the top you will see App Services

Comment: Oh, that's confusing, mine are all "classic", I'll have to see if I can use the new style with PHP. Thx

Comment: Web apps are not the new cloud apps, they are the new web sites including mobile and API. They do not offer the same functionality that cloud services (cloud apps) have, such as startup tasks, so I am still needing the same answers if possible.

Comment: startup task it s a webjob that can be created inside web app service too, i know they arent the same but it will be replaced by the brand new, thats why the "classic" diferentiation, test some dummy php project in web app and check the settings available